# editing product listing phtml messes up layout

Tags: layout

I'm sorry I cannot share a live page to show this issue, but I hope you can still make some sense of it.

I've created a new product listing page which I reference using

```
<reference name="content">
<block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" template="catalog/product/my-simple-product-list.phtml">
</block>
</reference>
```

in my category panel, custom layout update.

This version of the product list template simply tried to create a pure text listing of the products, so I remove the images and formating etc + all extra features like buttons. In the end, you get a simple listing of the products in the category. Just what I want, great.

However, when I try to wrap this list in a table, the whole page layout falls apart.

I have entered the following at the top of the page:

```
<!-- start of table, show header -->
    <table>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Product Name</td>
        <td>SKU Number</td>
    </tr>
<!-- end of table header -->
```

The actual table function works, but it messes up the page. The left column goes "right and under" the main page column, and the footer also gets squashed into the main page column.

From this litle information, is anyone able to advise what might be the problem there - and what can I do to avoid it?

Thanks.

update: i've added the code for this page here: http://pastebin.com/inWQh6zV

My table is currently created correctly, but my site side bar (on left), is pushed down below where the table ends.

update 2: I solved the issue! I moved the header of the table to the line below:  where the loop begins. This fixed the layout issue.

Comment: I solved the issue! I moved the header of the table to the line below: <?php $_iterator = 0; ?> where the loop begins. This fixed the layout issue.

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to add the `</table>` tag

Comment: indeed, I had forgotten that! duh! And that fixed the footer issue. However, my sidebar is still pushed below my table, but on the left hand side of the screen (where it should be). Its just lower than it should be - if that makes sense?

Comment: I guess I code post the page code somewhere if that helps?

Comment: Hi Marius, I've added my page code above - perhaps that helps identify the issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

From what you have provided, I would say its a html issue.

It sounds like you are missing a closing tag some where. Take a look at the source.